# how to detect spiral in an image using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, detection

I'm new to matlab, I'm not clear of how to detect the spirality and spiral center in an image using matlab.

For example I need to detect the spiral center of the galaxy.
Question: How to model spirality concept in these kind of spiral image for example....
Thank you.

original images taken from here:

- [storm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclone#mediaviewer/File:Low_pressure_system_over_Iceland.jpg)
- [galaxy](http://i.space.com/images/i/000/027/694/i02/m-74-spiral-galaxy.jpg?1364988866)

Comment: Well, first of all, optical flow requires two images of the same scene taken at different times in order to estimate the motion of the scene (or camera) during the time interval.

Comment: add more info like do you have the whole spiral in view or is the scene more complex (have more things on it) and specify closer input images storms and galaxies are very different what works for one can be invalid for the other one. Always try to be concrete about input as much as you can for computer vision algorithms (sadly they are still not universal)

Comment: I see you are new user so ... if the question is answered check the check sign near the correct answer (it will give the author points and mark the solution for others to see it quickly) if it is only helpful in some way you can vote up by clicking on the upper triangle or if it is wrong harm-full abusive ... then you can vote down by that lower triangle (can cast only 1 vote per question or answer) also this will award you some badges I think ... also you can vote the comments if you have enough points. also all votes are undo-able so do not worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Optical flow**

- is moving intensity/color of scene
- not image of an object !!!
- this is taken from flying insects vision
- they use it to:

  - determine flight direction (compensate wind drift)
  - navigation
  - collision avoidance
  - landing

**Spiral image**

- in your case you should look for geometry + density analysis (nothing to do with Optical flow)
- here are few things that pop up in my head for your case:

  1. **make density map**

     - find the biggest density
     - or density center
  2. **vectorise the whole thing**

     - find center mathematically
     - or look for joint of arms
     - or look for eye of the storm
     - also you can vectorise the gaps
     - if they are curved and rotated to each other then you have spiral
  3. **make gap occurence map**

     - number of gaps per square area
     - the bigger the count is the closer you are to center
     - beware inside center area can be 0 gaps
     - find max gap count positions
     - compute average middle between all of them
     - to improve accuracy you could segmentate gaps before
     - and count only different gaps per area

       [image: gap count]

**[Notes]**

- I would go for option 3
- it is most simple of all of them
- just few for loops
- you can also combine more approaches together to improve accuracy
- **use proper filtrations and color reduction/tresholding before detection**

  - like sharpening, artifact reduction, smoothing, erosion/corosion ...

Comment: Can you please enlighten me a little bit more about the vectorization?
Thank you.

Comment: @user3416340 vectorisation is uneasy task covering entire books. usualy is edge detection applied then its contours are extracted as lines, missing pieces are interpolated and artifacts are deleted ... then this list of lines are grouped to polygons ('close' loop finding) so the result is list of polylines/polygons in vector form. this data is easier analysable by programming means then raster bitmap data.

Comment: Can you guide me how to detect the cyclone center in this case
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wettest_tropical_cyclones_by_country#mediaviewer/File:Hurricane_Alma.jpg

Comment: @user3416340 not without actually do it ... you can not use generic approach for CV (computer vision) apps only trial&error + some heuristic based on your experience with the subject (that is why I provided more options) you should chose one that is easiest for you (or any other) try it and see if it is the way if not improve it or use something else. At first step you should filter the input image to remove redundant data as much as possible... Do not expect that someone will code this for you unless (s)he need it too or already has it done. (There is no effort from your side ...)